# Saving Drawable reference into SQLite Database

Tags: database, drawable

I want to save the reference (the integer) of .png files saved in the /drawable folder in my Android App.

I wish to use them as a SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 in my suggestions list, therefore the address needs to be stored in the DB.

Knowing just the name of the file (for example: fruitsicon.png) which value should I save in the database, in order to specify the COLUMN as SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I insert in the DB column

```
android.resource://com.mydomain.appname/drawable/icon1
```

It worked